# Return a query with nested results with Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord

I'm trying to grab a list of active tasks for a workflow tool I'm making, with the data structured like this:

- User

  - has_many Projects

    - has_many Subprojects

      - has_many Tasks

        - has_many TimeLogs

Active tasks are defined as any task with a TimeLog that does not have a 'completed' timestamp.

I'm trying to make the main page display this full structure, but only show parent structures that have an active task at some level. Any Users/Projects/Subprojects that don't have an active task beneath them should not be returned by the query.

So far I've tried:

- A join on all four tables, which produces duplicate rows
- A WHERE EXISTS statement, which returns only the relevant users, but doesn't maintain the WHERE clause when I try to access its children

Is there a way to achieve this without manually culling the data in Ruby?

Comment: You can add `.uniq` onto the end of your join query.  ActiveRecord will then query without the duplicates.

Comment: That works for the top-level Users, but when I grab the child Projects of a User, it just grabs all projects. Carrying down the `where` clause through the children seems messy, so I'm looking for a way to just grab it all at once, maybe convert the ActiveRecord query to a nested Hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nested level of problem it might be quite complicated. As I understand, you want to omit users|projects|subprojects, that do not have any active tasks. There's no simple sql that will let you achieve that by:

```
users.each do |user|
  user.active_projects.each do |project|
    ...
  end
end
```

Instead, I would query for tasks first, i.e. `@tasks = Task.includes(:subproject => [:project => :user]).where("status NOT IN ('completed')")`. Then you have incompleted tasks and now all you need to do is to reorder fetched data, I mean:

```
@tasks = @tasks
.group_by {|t| t.subproject.project.user }
.reduce({}) do |sum, (user, tasks)|
  sum[user] ||= {}
  tasks.each do |task|
    sum[user][task.subproject.project] ||= {}
    sum[user][task.subproject.project][task.subproject] ||= []
    sum[user][task.subproject.project][task.subproject] << task 
  end
  sum
end
```

I haven't tested this, but that's the idea.

Comment: Bleh, so the best way to do this is by constructing the tree manually. I was worried that was going to be the case. Thanks for the code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this based on the [activerecord queries documents](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations):

```
user.projects.joins(subprojects: { tasks: [{ time_logs: { timestamp: 'completed'} }] })
```

I can't test it, but give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was my first idea, but joins returns duplicate rows if a User has more than one active task, and as I mentioned in the comments, `.uniq` doesn't apply the `where` clause to child relations.